# how to use for-each-group?

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml:

```
<articles>
    <article>
<metadata>
<type>work</type>
</metadta>
<content>work force</content>
    </article>

    <article>
<metadata>
<type>sport</type>
</metadta>
<content>cricket s gentle man game</content>
    </article>

    <article>
<metadata>
<type>Life</type>
</metadta>
<content>Life is beatiful</content>
    </article>
    </articles>
```

my xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="article" group-by="type">
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
<xsl:value-of select="content/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I am getting:
work force
cricket s gentle man game
Life is beatiful

work force
cricket s gentle man game
Life is beatiful

work force
cricket s gentle man game
Life is beatiful

(i.e, no of type)
just i need:
work force
cricket s gentle man game
Life is beatiful

Comment: Please add an example XML file to your question that shows the structure you're trying to process. Also let us know the expected result of the transformation.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still not a working example that reproduces your problem. The XML isn't well-formed (`<metadata>...</metadta>`). Also the XSLT snippet doesn't quite fit to the XML structure. Instead of `group-by="type"` you probably mean `group-by="metadata/type"`. After correcting these things, the grouping should work as expected. If the for-each-group loop is executed multiple times, you probably call the corresponding template several times. Thus, please provide a complete example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @XSLT_FRESHER Actually, in the given example, you don't actually need grouping at all, as all your articles have different **type** elements. You might want show some sample XML with repeated types. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want group-by="metadata/type".